# Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15

Tags: поддержка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, на что влияют голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15?

"Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга."

Answer (score -1):

Вероятно, вы говорите о привилегии https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up.

Как сказано в пояснении, которое вы привели, такие голоса записываются системой, но не учитываются в общем рейтинге сообщения.